# How to post asset image to server using MultipartFile in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am using `MultipartFile` to send my image file to server. I know that when I use `ImagePicker`

```
File ImageFile;

  _openCamera() async {
    var picture = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
    this.setState(() {
      imageFile = picture;
    });
  }
```

then use `MultipartFile` like this

```
request.files.add(http.MultipartFile.fromBytes('img', ImageFile.readAsBytesSync(), filename: 'photo.jpg'));
```

But my problem is I want my image is from my **assets** like from here `Image.asset('images/photo1.png');`. I have error

```
A value of type 'Image' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'File'.
Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'File'.
```

So, my question is how I can send my image using `MultipartFile` method?

Comment: Did you try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'File'?

Comment: Did you not try to do the same thing, and received and accepted an answer already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60789304/how-to-upload-image-in-flutter)?

Comment: it is different, one is File one is asset. I cannot use that method, have error like I show above

Comment: Did you try to do what the error message was telling you?

Comment: Load the asset as a list of bytes, then use that as the second parameter of fromBytes. Use await rootBundle.load to get a ByteData. Then .buffer.asUint8List to turn the byte data into a byte list.

Comment: @mkrieger I failed to convert image to file

Comment: @Richard Heap thank you for your reply. I will try it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, obtain the asset as list of bytes:

```
  var bytes = (await rootBundle.load('images/photo1.png')).buffer.asUint8List();
```

Then use that in the `MultipartFile` named constructor:

```
  var mpFile = http.MultipartFile.fromBytes('img', bytes, filename: 'photo.jpg');
```